# Android: Sliding tabs (toolbar at bottom)

Tags: android, tabs, toolbar

I would like to have like a toolbar at button. I know it goes against Android guidelines, but I am planning to only enable it for clients that specificly ask for it.

I imagine a low height bar at bottom looking like this: [item1][item2][item3] followed by more items outside visible area. People should then be able to slide it to see the rest of the items.

I don't want to host multiple activites etc. They are simply an extra convenience bar of shortcouts to (possibly dynamicly determined) popular areas in the app. (Not menu items/actionbar items like e.g. "share", "preferences" etc.)

I have sene what I want in some apps, but I am not sure what the control is called. It seems that it is not a built-in control? (At least the tabs support I see seems a little different and requires e.g. a TabHost)

Comment: I'm not really sure if I get you right what you are asking for...if you show us an exam from these apps which you are talking about we can help you more with the right approach how to build them.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems that you want to create a thin ViewPager at the bottom of your screen: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)?

Comment: I think I was. Thanks. It seems to do what I need.